# How to prepare data.frame for keras using tensoflow CNN in r

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I have been trying to prepare a train data set for CNN in keras, but i can't find the way to properly set the data.

In the keras [CNN example](https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/examples/mnist_cnn.html), they use the MNIST data set, in which:

```
library(keras)

img_rows <- 28

img_cols <- 28

mnist <- dataset_mnist()

x_train <- mnist$train$x

x_train <- array_reshape(x_train, c(nrow(x_train), img_rows, img_cols, 1))
```

Which outputs an array with this dim:

```
class(x_train)
[1] "array"

dim(x_train)
[1] 60000    28    28     1
```

I have a dataframe like this:

```
x = data.frame(c(1,10,19,28),c(2,11,20,29),c(3,12,21,30),c(4,13,22,31),c(5,14,23,32),c(6,15,24,33),c(7,16,25,34),c(8,17,26,35),c(9,18,27,36))
```

Each row represent a 3x3 image like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I am trying this:

```
x = as.integer(unlist(x))

x = array_reshape(x, c(4,3,3, 1))
```

This return 3 matrices with scramble numbers.  ¿How can I properly transform my data.frame for a CNN in keras?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do, its to reshape your training data (`x`) into an array of of 4 elements with 3x3 matrices each. If that is in fact the case then try this,

```
> aperm(array(t(x), dim = c(3, 3, 4)), perm = c(2,1,3))

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   11   12
[2,]   13   14   15
[3,]   16   17   18

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   19   20   21
[2,]   22   23   24
[3,]   25   26   27

, , 4

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   28   29   30
[2,]   31   32   33
[3,]   34   35   36
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solutions gives me an object with 
dim(x) 
3 3 4

I am looking for an object with a dim
4 3 3 1

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
# Create an empty array the size you want    
x_array <- array(NA, dim = c(3, 3, length(x)))

# Loop in each object of your list into the array
for (i in length(x)) {
  x_array[,, i] <- x[[i]]
}
```